# Why does Minecraft instantly disconnect me from LAN servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I try playing on LAN, it just says "failed to connect to server", and in bold underneath it says "disconnected". What could be the possible causes of this, and how could I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade SE, take [the tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already and read [the help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) if in need of more guidance. You should add more details about what you are sure about and what you already did and try. Are you sure you are on the same network as the server host? Are you sure the IP is right?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the possible causes:

1. Your friends are banning you (if it's their server)
2. A glitch, bug
3. The connection is weak
4. If it's your friend's server, and the friend that made the server leaves, that will instantly disconnect you from the server
5. If it's a public server, there's always an AI watching players, so maybe the AI thought you're cheating even though you were not. (That happened to me)

Comment: 1. Bans are given as an explicit reason, not just "failed to connect".
2. Very unlikely.
3. One of the likely causes.
4. Also possible but probably not the case.
5. It's a LAN, not a public server.

Comment: :) sorry, im new to minecraft, sorry for any mistakes

Comment: It prob bad connection or bug but most likely connection cause it on two different cp. Thnx. It is not ban cause it happen on two different cp and different accounts. It is not public so not an ai. It is not them leaving cause we in same house. And with one in the same room. So thank you

Comment: This post does a reasonable job at attempting to answer the question. Down voters please advise on what needs to be improved. I've added a +1 to bring it up to even and I suggest editing the answer per Corsaka's comment. @InfiniteEnternitis